# PHP Get strings / numbers in the RIGHT order

Tags: php, arrays

I'm tired of arrays and lists like this:

```
Array(
    [0] Item 1
    [1] Item 10
    [2] Item 11
    [3] Item 2
    [4] Item 3
    )
```

Does PHP have a quick method to display this in order so that 10 comes AFTER 1, 2, 3... ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you need natural sorting algorithm. 
[natsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) function in PHP does it.

```
$items = array('item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3', 'item 10');
natsort($items);
print_r($items)
```

Output

> Array ( [0] => item 1 [1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) => item 2 [2] => item 3 [3] => item 10 )

Comment: DEADLY! Wow, wish I knew about this years ago. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Try the function sort :

```
sort(<array-name> , SORT_NUMERIC);
```

It will sort numeric values in the array in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

use following php function:

```
<?php
$myArray = array("0" => "1", "1" => "10", "2" => "11", "3" => "2", "4" => "3");

asort($myArray);

foreach($myArray as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key - $value <br />";
}
?>
```

here is the example: [sort number with string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php)

Comment: This is no way answers the OPs question, as your `$myArray` is completely different.

Comment: sorry,, ,use `natsort()` function, it sorts both number and string. .